# running app from VMware

Tags: ios, vmware

I want to run my app from VMware Xcode on my iPhone but the VMware doesn't
 display the connected device, I found an answer that that from setting> hardware > chose usb 2.0 and show all connected devices.
in my setting show connected device can't be actived

Comment: If you found the answer please add it down here